# F# Interactive Not Working in Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin-studio, f#-interactive

For some reason, when I try to use the F# Interactive window, it's just a white screen (as shown in the attached photo). Even when I select a line of code and sent it to F# interactive nothing happens.

I can compile `.fs` files just fine and I'm able to get to and run the `fsharpi` that Xamarin Studio is pointing to. I'm not sure if it's something about how it gets from the `fsharpi` to the window, but I can't figure out another way to fix this. I've tried reinstalling but get the same results.

Anybody have any thoughts or would this actually be better to submit a bug to them about? Thanks!

[image: F# Interactive window]

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me too, I was changing the color of the F# interactive window to match the style I had.
 After changing just the font color, the screen stayed totally white. I tried to reset the window in 
Preferences -> Other -> Settings
Still didn't work, I found a way to use F# interactive calling it directly using a command prompt. 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.10.0/bin/fsharpi

Edit: Changing settings just resetted the font size to 0, just change it back. This works for me.

Comment: Interesting, that may be what happened to mine. I actually did a full uninstall using a third party uninstaller and re-installed. Now it's back up and running! Thanks for taking the time to reply.